# Адаптация темы VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Скажите пожалуйста как можно адаптировать (изменить) под себя уже установленную тему VS Code из маркета.

Например, нравятся темы Cobalt2 и Night Owl, но хотелось бы несколько изменить подсветку синтаксиса, а именно сделать подсветку тегов красным цветом.
Можно ли внести подобные изменения в тему и пересохранить для дальнейшего использования? И если можно, то как это сделать? )

Answer (score 1):

Переходишь по ссылке и можешь в режиме онлайн себе всё сделать https://themes.vscode.one/

Comment: Все бы хорошо, но как там выбрать уже имеющуюся тему (например Cobalt2), чтобы потом в нее внести изменения? Я даже поиска по темам не нашел

Comment: Тогда копируешь json темы cobalt (можешь взять тут https://github.com/wesbos/cobalt2-vscode/blob/master/theme/cobalt2.json), а потом следуешь с пункта "Установка своей темы в VS Code" в статье https://habr.com/ru/articles/276997/

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Нужно найти файл .json темы, которую хочется подкорректировать, напр. Night Owl:
C:\Users\UserName\ >>> .vscode\extensions\sdras.night-owl-2.0.1\themes
Сохранить копию на всякий случай;
Открыть .json в VS CODE и отредактировать нужные параметры, а как найти параметры для редактирования, рассказано здесь:
https://youtu.be/Su-cNLe0dgw?si=YSU9mMHikF_l3UzO
Сохраняем отредактированный .json, перезагружаем VS CODE – готово, все внесённые изменения появились в теме.

PS: Дополнение к видео в ссылке:
"Developer: Inspect TM Scopes"
теперь называется -
"Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes"